# QT tree that allows multiselection

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm making a simple file explorer and I ran into some problems with Qt. I want to show the user a tree view of files on his computer, but I also want to be able to select multiple files/directories and do something with them later on (by selecting `checkboxes` or multiple select using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd>). I've placed the `QTreeView` element and set up a model to it (`QFileSystemModel`). It gives me a good tree view, but I can't modify the headers (column names) or add my own column with `checkbox` in every row (for example). Qt is new to me, I've searched for few good hours for some tips/solutions, but nothing is working with `QFileSystemModel`. Is there anything I can do to get this working?

The code is short and simple:

```
QString lPath = "C:/";
QString rPath = "C:/";
leftTree_model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
rightTree_model = new QFileSystemModel(this);

leftTree_model->setRootPath(lPath);
rightTree_model->setRootPath(rPath);

//i have actually 2 tree views that work the same
ui->leftTree->setModel(leftTree_model); //ui->leftTree is the first tree view
ui->rightTree->setModel(rightTree_model); //the second
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something of the following:

[CheckStateRole](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) to add checkboxes to your model. To do this, you inherit your custom item model (which you're going to use) from the `QFileSystemModel`, and reimplement the `data()` method, where you return `bool` values for `CheckStateRole`. You will also need the `QAbstractItemModel::setData` method to handle changes. You can also check the [docs for QAbstractItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html) to see how to change header texts (`headerData()`)

Change the [selection mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) of your view to allow multiple selections

EDIT:
here's a sample code to inherit from the model

```
  class MyFancyModel : public QFileSystemModel
  {
  public:
    MyFancyModel(QObject* pParent = NULL) : QFileSystemModel(pParent)
    {
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const
    {
      if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
      {
        // stub value is true
        return true;  // here you will return real values 
                      // depending on which item is currently checked
      }
      return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
    }
  };
```

Comment: could you expand your answer a little bit more? I get the selection mode, did it already. I get the inheritance, (`class treeModel : public QFileSystemModel`), but I'm having problem with the `treeModel` constructor (error: unresolved external symbol...). I'm replacing the `leftTree_model = new QFileSystemModel(this);` with `leftTree_model = new treeModel(this);`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have another problem. The checkboxes are clickable, but they present a strange behavior. If I click one checkbox, release mouse button and move my cursor over every checkbox, they all are checked. Here you have the code: http://ideone.com/Xrrdo9. What do I do wrong?

Comment: that's because you return the same status for every row regardless of the item which was checked: `return checkstatus;` How is the view supposed to know, which checkbox of all of them needs to be checked?

Comment: So I should store every index and status of the checkbox corresponding to it?

Comment: or, you could store the items which _are selected_. And this is what you want in the first place

Comment: Ok, I've handled it using QHash, but when I click on the checkboxes, they are toggled only when I move my cursor somewhere else. They are not updated right away. What could be the problem?

Comment: you need to implement your [setData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) properly (dataChanged() signal)